# onAdFailedToLoad: 0 ошибка при попытке интегрировать рекламу

Tags: admob, flutter

```
W/flutter ( 2864): onAdFailedToLoad: 0
I/Ads     ( 2864): Ad failed to load : 0
I/flutter ( 2864): BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad
```

в чем может быть проблема?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

const String testDevice = 'Mobile_id';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo;
  BannerAd myBanner;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
      keywords: <String>['flutterio', 'beautiful apps'],
      contentUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
      birthday: DateTime.now(),
      childDirected: false,
      designedForFamilies: false,
      gender: MobileAdGender
          .male, // or MobileAdGender.female, MobileAdGender.unknown
      testDevices: <String>[], // Android emulators are considered test devices
    );
    myBanner = BannerAd(
      // Replace the testAdUnitId with an ad unit id from the AdMob dash.
      // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
      // https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads
      adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.smartBanner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event is $event");
      },
    );
  }

  void _show_banner() {
    myBanner
      ..load()
      ..show(
        anchorOffset: 0.0,
        anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Title',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('data'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => _show_banner(),
                child: Text('Show Banner Ad'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

так же добавил тег в `AndroidManifest.xml` после

```
<application>

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
</application>
```

Comment: рекомендую не светить app ids, adunit ids и подобное, тк люди могут создать приложение с вашими кредами и с них нарушать правила адмоба, за что вашему аккаунту адмоба могут дать бан (им никакой выгоды этого делать нет, но на всякий случай).

Comment: app id в данном коде является тестовый вроде

Comment: да, точно, тестовый. Тогда возможно проблема в интеграции, сейчас дополню ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно ошибка **0** означает их внутреннюю ошибку, то есть с интеграцией всё хорошо скорее всего.

Попробуйте подождать, такое может происходить, т.к. реклама была недавно создана/аккаунт недавно зарегистрирован.

Также причиной может быть то, что в личном кабинете `AdMob` не указаны payment details.

Поэтому стоит просто подождать, а если хотите проверить именно вашу интеграцию, используйте тестовый режим.

**Дополнение ответа:**

Я так понял, вы используете `Firebase AdMob`. Я посмотрел ваш код и не увидел инициализации, попробуйте в метод `initState()` добавить инициализацию с вашим `app id`:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    /// Тут мы добавили тестовый, как будете выкладывать в релиз, замените своим
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
    targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
      keywords: <String>['flutterio', 'beautiful apps'],
      contentUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
      birthday: DateTime.now(),
      childDirected: false,
      designedForFamilies: false,
      gender: MobileAdGender
          .male, // or MobileAdGender.female, MobileAdGender.unknown
      testDevices: <String>[], // Android emulators are considered test devices
    );
    myBanner = BannerAd(
      // Replace the testAdUnitId with an ad unit id from the AdMob dash.
      // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
      // https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads
      adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.smartBanner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event is $event");
      },
    );
  }
```